# Send Request payload using python scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to scrape a website where I can find the url has a post request with payload parameters as below. I am not sure how to make it to a dictionary in payload and send it in formdata. All the below code comes under Request with payload how do I send this in formdata??

```
    ------WebKitFormBoundaryj9yKl83Zu7ki71zE
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="textquery"

    852432-B21
    ------WebKitFormBoundaryj9yKl83Zu7ki71zE--
```

How to format this and do I send this using python-scrapy?

Answer (score 1):

You should send it as raw request body with appropriate header:

```
body = '''--WebKitFormBoundaryj9yKl83Zu7ki71zE
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="textquery"

852432-B21
--WebKitFormBoundaryj9yKl83Zu7ki71zE--
'''

yield Request(url, method='POST', body=body, 
              headers={'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=WebKitFormBoundaryj9yKl83Zu7ki71zE'})
```

Comment: Looks correct but it didn't work but I think the reason is boundary value. I don't understand the concept behind "boundary" value. Can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Concept is corresponding RFC http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1867.html I modified answer.

Comment: Nope, didn't work! I get 500 internal server error. How boundary value is allocated and  how can I fetch it, is there a way?